# Where are SMS Drafts stored?

Tags: java, android, sms, telephony

I have searched and searched and cannot seem to pull data from the draft's folder within the device. Basically I am wanting to pull the typed (unsent) message from the user's conversation, my thinking is that it was stored within Android as a draft. However if I try to search the draft folder using the uri-

```
 Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/draft/");
```

No data is returned. I have adjusted it to remove the 'draft' portion and it does return all my inbox messages. I have ensured that the permissions have been set and accepted.

Comment: Since Marshmallow, on standard systems, only the default messaging app has access to draft messages in the SMS Provider. Non-defaults only have access to sent and inbox messages. Which version are you testing on? Is your app the current default messaging app?

Comment: I am testing on Oreo and my app is not the current default messaging app. I was hoping I could tap into the system and read these defaults. Is there any way around this where I could read the drafts or is it pretty much locked out? Maybe an accessibility addition?

Comment: Nope, not like that. Possibly with root, but that's probably not helpful.

Comment: There anyway I could possibly receive a Broadcast from the device that can let me know a Draft has been created?

Comment: Nope, there is no broadcast when that happens.

Comment: how about conversations and utilize a thread_id in order to retrieve everything inside of it? Surely a draft would be a message with no state / type?

Comment: Draft messages do have a type, [`MESSAGE_TYPE_DRAFT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.html#MESSAGE_TYPE_DRAFT). The restricted view for non-defaults includes only `MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX` and `MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT`: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/TelephonyProvider/+/master/src/com/android/providers/telephony/MmsSmsDatabaseHelper.java#931.